# Android получение файла не из ресурсов

Tags: java, android

Необходимо создать `Bitmap` из изображения png, находящегося не в ресурсах, а просто в папке проекта. Не могу понять какой путь прописывать, пробовал через `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(путь к файлу)` и также пробовал просто получить этот файл  через `new File(путь к файлу)`.

Возможно ли вообще такое сделать? Или андроид работает только с изображениями из ресурсов?

И если возможно, то какой прописывать путь до файла? если допустим он находится в корне проекта. Просто имя файла в данном случае не работает.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите добавить данное изображение в ресурсы? В крайнем случае можно сохранить base64 от картинки в виде строки в самом коде, только это неоптимально и достаточно странно.

Comment: просто есть готовая архитектура проекта на java для свинга и переносится на андроид, хотел понять есть ли возможность оставить текущее расположение файлов или надо их обязательно переносить?

Comment: А смысл оставлять архитектуру, если у Вас всё равно нет готового кода с этой архитектурой работающего. Можно конечно открыть поток через [`getResourceAsStream("/путь/в/apk/image.png")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), но не все файлы проекта в APK упаковываются - нужно что бы он лежал в правильном месте.

Comment: Спасибо, немного разобрался, надо будет делать через ресурсы

Comment: @berek можно написать обёртку, которая в Swing версии будет считывать картинки откуда там нужно, а в Android версии - из ресурсов. А в бизнес-коде, который един для обеих версий, достаточно будет вызывать нужные методы обёртки.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы понять посмотрите на то каким образом идет сборка проекта, вам важно понять что фактически то что лежит в папке проекта [запаковывается в APK bundle](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size) - причем при некоторых ситуациях не все может попасть. Реально файлы на файловую системы устройства никогда не распаковываются, и Android работает со ZIP стримом делая маппинг в память. Если все таки вам надо так делать вам надо работать с файлами через специальный Asset Manager:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

InputStream istr;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
    istr = assetManager.open(filePath);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    if(isrt != null) istr.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Также имейте в виду что есть ограничение на размер APK, и для того чтобы динамически подгружать можно пользоваться механизмом [APK Expansion Files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#Overview)

Comment: Спасибо, видимо придется делать через ресурсы, что и правильнее.